# git command return not authorized when pushing changes on the repository

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I am trying to push the changes on the repository of a project, but when i try to push the changes

the git command return with an error "not authorized".

Comment: What was the issue in your case? Did you use HTTPS or SSH?

Comment: Is the re an issue with the answer (which was accepted)?

Answer (score 0):

That means the authentication has been rejected as incorrect.
Check the output of `git remote -v`

- either you are using an HTTPS URL (`https://github.com/me/myRepo`), in which case you need the right user account name and [GitHub PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).
  Check if you have a credential helper, which might have cached the wrong credentials (`git config --global credential.helper`)
- or you are using an SSH URL (`git@github.com:me/myRepo`) and you need your public key correctly [registered to your GitHub SSH setting page](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).
  Check what SSH key is used with  `ssh -Tv git@github.com`.